# How to export get request parameters to another JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, export

app.js

```
app.get('/save', function(req,res){

var switchInput = { 
    sw1: req.query.switch1,
    sw2: req.query.switch2,
    sw3: req.query.switch3,
    sw4: req.query.switch4,
    sw5: req.query.switch5,
    sw6: req.query.switch6,
}

console.log(switchInput);  
module.exports = switchInput

res.send(switchInput); 

});
```

simulate.js

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var suit = require('../app')

...

function batteryLife(t){  
    var elapsed = Date.now() - t;
    t_remaining = fullTime - elapsed; 
    t_battery = secondsToHms(Math.floor(t_remaining/1000));
   //console.log(Math.floor(elapsed/1000) + ' s');

    console.log(suit.sw1);

    return t_battery; 
};
```

Console Log:

```
{ sw1: 'true',
  sw2: 'true',
  sw3: 'true',
  sw4: 'true',
  sw5: 'true',
  sw6: 'true' }
--------------Simulation started--------------
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
--------------Simulation stopped--------------
```

When I try to access these values from a different js file they print as undefined I am using postman to simulate values

The values will log from here but print undefined from the other js file

Is there a way to correct this I'm not sure what I am doing wrong 
the values are loading into "inputSwitch" but are not coming out on the simulate.js side

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting on an event which isn't a good idea. What you can do instead is call a function in the other file where you need values with the values.

**Example**

app.js

```
const simulate = require('./simulate');
app.get('/save', function(req,res){

var switchInput = { 
    sw1: req.query.switch1,
    sw2: req.query.switch2,
    sw3: req.query.switch3,
    sw4: req.query.switch4,
    sw5: req.query.switch5,
    sw6: req.query.switch6,
}

simulate(switchInput);

res.send(switchInput); 

});
```

simulate.js

```
module.exports = function(input){
   //have all your functions and code that require input here
   function foo(){...}
   function bar(){...}
}
```

Comment: thanks this helps, however I want to use the values in the simulate.js file in several different functions can you elaborate a little more on how that would be done? sorry i'm faily new to node js

Comment: @GeraldoCisneros made the edit. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while using youre favorite webserver like Express, you request aka (req) will/could flow amongst middleware before reaching your specific endpoint. Which means your req params are accessible at anytime there which could help you for specific code logic [middleware-the-core-of-node-js-apps](https://hackernoon.com/middleware-the-core-of-node-js-apps-ab01fee39200).

I agree with vibhor1997a, you should not export something there, basically you only `module.exports` "things" at the end of a file, not something at run-time.

You could do if you really want to deal with `switchInput` in another file do :

- do what vibhor1997a suggest (sync or async function)
- have a middleware before reaching your endpoint
- raised an event with your `switchInput` as argument [example](https://appdividend.com/2017/10/16/node-js-events-eventemitter-tutorial-example-scratch/)